# Script that allows microphone to test if there is sound

Tags: audio, script, batch-file, microphone, vbscript

Is there a command that reads the level of sound a microphone is receiving?

I'm attempting to make a small program, that is referenced by HTML.

My main question is just how to get a script that can test true if mic input audio is above like 10%.

I notice that it could be done using html API's
with: `var audioContext = new AudioContext();`, 
but how would I just test whether or not the mic is able to hear anything?

My end purpose is to incorporate all of this into an HTA

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whole example in HTA with vbscript :

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
APPLICATIONNAME="Volume + - ON/OFF" 
BORDER="THIN" 
BORDERSTYLE="NORMAL" 
ICON="SndVol.exe" 
INNERBORDER="NO" 
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO" 
MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO" 
SCROLL="NO" 
SELECTION="NO" 
SINGLEINSTANCE="YES"/>
<title>Volume + - ON/OFF </title>
<script language="vbscript">
'************************************************************************************
Sub window_onload()
    CenterWindow 250,150
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
Sub Volume(Param)
    set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    Select Case Param 
    Case "MAX"
        oShell.SendKeys "{" & chr(175) & " 50}" ' volume maximum 100%
    Case "MIN"
        oShell.SendKeys "{" & chr(174) & " 50}" 'volume minimum 0% 
    Case "UP"
        oShell.SendKeys "{" & chr(175) & " 10}" 'volume +20%
    Case "DOWN"
        oShell.SendKeys "{" & chr(174) & " 10}" 'volume +20%
    Case "MUTE"
        oShell.SendKeys chr(173) 'permet de couper/remettre le son (bascule)
    End select
End Sub
'*************************************************************************************
Sub Volume(Param1,Param2,Param3)
    set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    oShell.SendKeys Param1 & chr(Param2) & Param3
    '--------------------------- MEMO ----------------------------------
    'oShell.SendKeys "{" & chr(175) & " 50}" ' volume maximum 100%
    'oShell.SendKeys "{" & chr(174) & " 50}" 'volume minimum 0% 
    'oShell.SendKeys "{" & chr(175) & " 10}" 'volume +20%
    'oShell.SendKeys "{" & chr(174) & " 10}" 'volume +20%
    'oShell.SendKeys chr(173) 'permet de couper/remettre le son (bascule)
End Sub
'*************************************************************************************
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<!--<BUTTON style="background: Red; color: white;" onClick="Call Volume('MAX')" style="WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume MAX</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON style="background: Blue; color: white;" onClick="Call Volume('MIN')" style="WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume MIN</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON style="background: Green; color: white;" onClick="Call Volume('UP')" style="WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume +20%</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON style="background: Orange; color: white;" onClick="Call Volume('DOWN')" style="WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume -20%</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON style="background: DarkOrange; color: white;" onClick="Call Volume('MUTE')" style="WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">ON/OFF</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;-->
<BUTTON onClick="Call Volume('{','175',' 50}')" style="background: Red; color: white;WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume MAX</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON onClick="Call Volume('{','174',' 50}')" style="background: Blue; color: white;WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume MIN</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON onClick="Call Volume('{','175',' 10}')" style="background: Green; color: white;WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume +20%</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON onClick="Call Volume('{','174',' 10}')" style="background: Orange; color: white;WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume -20%</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON onClick="Call Volume('','173','')" style="background: DarkOrange; color: white;WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">ON/OFF</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</center>
</body>
</html>
```